# Getting USB stats in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver

Is there a way to get USB stats in Linux? I am trying to figure out how many data bytes were received by a Linux host through a given USB connection.

I have a microcontroller talking to a Linux based host. As soon as I start it, it works. But the host application stops receiving any data from the microcontroller after a while. Microcontroller debugging suggested me that the data was sent out.

So I am trying to figure out whether the host receive any data at USB driver level. Or whether there was an error when trying to receive the data.

Are there any Linux USB counters I can check for this?

Thank you!

Comment: The Linux kernel being open source, you could in principle improve it for that purpose

Comment: Alternatively, libusb is also open source, so you might add your instrumentation in user-space.

Comment: Have you checked [usbmon](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/usb/usbmon.rst)?

Comment: You can also use Wireshark (or tshark) to capture USB packets via usbmon.

Answer (score 0):

Try `usbtop` and use `sudo` privilege if required.